# Nginx redirects requests for Laravel to React ignoring location directive

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx

I have a **Laravel** application with a **React** frontend.

I needed Laravel to answer to:

- every route starting with `/api`
- the exact route `/attempt_login`
- the exact route `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`

While react has to answer to all the remaining routes.

This works fine for every single route, apart from `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`.
Every time I call that url I get an answer from React.

Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        index index.php index.html;
        server_name servername;
        root backend_path;

        location ~ /api {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /attempt_login {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /sanctum {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location / {
                root frontend_path;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
#               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I tried with:

- `location /sanctum {`
- `location ~ /sanctum {`
- `location = /sanctum/csrf-cookie {`
- `location /sanctum/csrf-cookie {`
- `location ~ /sanctum/csrf-cookie {`

Each and every one of them gave the same result (yes, I restarted nginx after each change)

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Maybe you get redirect response first and then it goes to react app? Also for testing purposes you can try return directive insted of try_files just to see that nginx config is correct. Like `return 200 "i am in sanctum"`;

Comment: @Grin That's a good idea, thank you, I will try that. Regarding the redirect it looks like the request answers with 200 directly, a redirect would return a 302 and then make a second call if i'm not wrong

Comment: @Grin I'm bashing my head on my desk....I wanted to try your suggestion, so I commented the `try_files` and put the `return` underneath....now it works as intended.....without changing anything else....

Comment: So, location section does work?
 How do you test requests? If with curl - it follows redirects automatically. And if you test it in browser - you have to check  "preserve log" option to see redirects in action. btw, I use Insomnia for such tests.

Comment: @Grin yes, for some reason `location /sanctum { return 200 "I am sanctum" }` does what `try_files` should have done, what I was trying to achieve. I don't know why or how, but since it works I'm not complaining

Comment: But you need try_files so index.php would process this request, return was just to prove the point that location works as should.

Comment: @Grin yes, I know, but it's working nontheless. I don't want to break anything, so I'll leave it like this for now. Maybe there was a conflict between paths and 2 locations were trying to serve, while now everything is handled by the same location. I really have no idea